# Take JSON with @POST on Restful

Tags: java, json, rest, post

I'm trying to take JSON values on POST method but I don't know how to do this.

This is the code that I have:

```
@POST
@Path("/contacts")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
public void addContact() {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    UserPK user = new UserPK((String) session.getAttribute("username"));
    //dest = TAKE JSON VALUE

    dao.addContact(user, dest);
}
```

I'm sending the JSON value with firefox RestClient with this look:

```
{"param1":"value"}
```

How can I take this value?

We also have this error message: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Is "dest" your JSON object or is it just the value from your JSON object that you extract? When does the error message occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are actually sending a post and the content-type of your request is application/json. To consume this with spring MVC you can use the @RequestBody annotation:

```
@POST
@Path("/contacts")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
public void addContact(@RequestBody MyClass c) {
```

Where MyClass is a simple java class representing the request object (i.e. in this case you would just need one String class variable named param1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using springmvc, it comes with message converter for json.
You may have to declare your pojo as a parameter in your method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the plugin from firefox didn't allow me to modify the headers, so when I tryed with text/plain on chrome with postman it worked.

Thanks anyway.